# Installing Phusion Passenger for Nginx, can't find package libnginx-mod-http-passenger

Tags: nginx, passenger, phusion

I am using the tutorial at

`https://www.phusionpassenger.com/docs/tutorials/deploy_to_production/installations/oss/ownserver/ruby/nginx/`

to install Passenger (6.0.4) for use with Nginx. I get to the point where I'm installing the 'libnginx-mod-http-passenger' package, and get the following...

```
deploy@rpi-tick1:~ $ sudo apt-get install -y libnginx-mod-http-passenger
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libnginx-mod-http-passenger
```

I am installing for Raspbian-stretch (Debian), and have set up /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passsenger.list as shown below (as instructed in the tutorial)

```
deploy@rpi-tick1:~ $ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list 
deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger stretch main
```

It appears that repository contains only 'passenger-doc' packages. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Nobody?  I thought the Phusion-Passenger guys hung out here. Is there something else needed to explain the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue myself while testing out whether my passenger setup will work on an ARM based Ubuntu instance. I believe the cause is that package is available for amd64 but not ARM. I see that you are using Raspbian and Raspberry Pi's are ARM based systems.

Comment: Thanks for responding. If you find a workaround, please share!

Comment: It would have to be compiled for ARM. I suppose Phusion would have to be the one to do that.

Comment: So, two and a half years later, and this is still an issue. (With bullseye now.). I’m surprised that nobody is using rpi’s with passenger and nginx, as they claim that Apache is incompatible with action cable. Guess I’ll have to look into compiling it myself. Groan…

Comment: Oh, and I’m VERY impressed the support that Phusion gives their products on this site.  Crickets…